# map / filter in mongo console

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Is there a way to do something like this in the mongo console:

```
mongo
mongo $> db.collection.find().map(v => v.key)
```

maybe it's something like:

```
mongo $> db.collection.find().cursor.map(v => v.key)
```

Comment: maybe only in v3.6+, see: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/

Comment: What do you mean? The `map()` method has always existed. If you're using an old version of the shell ( before 3.2 I believe ) then the support for ES6 things like the arrow `=>` was not enabled in the JavaScript engine implemented. But the function itself has been around here and in other drivers since 2.0 at least.

Answer (score 0):

Following is an example of using filter to find all documents where the name matches the string *Sid* and print the value of the *name* property:

```
db.getCollection('People').find({ name: /Sid.*/ }).map(v => v.name);
```